# Square root argument of a complex number.

Tags: complex-numbers

How could I compute the argument of the following complex number:
$$\lambda=\sqrt{x^2-y^2+m^2-2isxy}$$
where, $s=\pm1,\,\,m\in\mathbb{R}$. I know for number in algebraic form $z=a+bi$ it's easy, just do, $arg(z)=\arctan\left(\dfrac{b}{a}\right)$ but unfortunately this is not the case.
Thank you in advanced.

Comment: Find the argument of the expression under the radical using what you know. Then halve it to find the argument of the square root.

Comment: Thanks. Could you indicate any material that has this that you have suggested?

Comment: It's standard elementary complex arithmetic. Pick a site you like from this search for _complex number arithmetic_: https://www.google.com/search?q=complex+number+arithmetic&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&client=firefox-b-1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Mostly when you are facing radicals, converting to polar coordinates is the key:

$z={x^2-y^2+m^2-2isxy}=a+bi$

$arg(z)=\arctan\left(\dfrac{b}{a}\right)$

$\|z\|=\sqrt{a^2+b^2}$

$\displaystyle\lambda=\|z\|^{1/2}e^{i\times arg(z)/2}$

- There is also another approach but I could not continue it:

$\displaystyle \lambda^2 =(x\pm iy)^2+m^2$

$\lambda_1=\sqrt{z^2+m^2}$

$\lambda_2=\sqrt{\bar z ^2+m^2}$

Comment: Thank you. Is it correct to say that $arg(\lambda)$ is the principal argument? That is indeed what I am looking for.

Comment: Glad I could help. The answer is yes. And that is equal to $arg(z)/2$. @D.Silva

Comment: Thanks for clarification. I did ContourPlot of $arg(\lambda)$ and I got what I expected.

Comment: @D.Silva Happy to hear that Silva.

Answer (score 0):

make the ansatz $$\sqrt{x^2-y^2+m^2-2sixy}=A+Bi$$

Comment: could you solve your Problem?

Comment: Yes, In a slightly more laborious way. But I decided to follow the procedure of Sr. Merhdad Zandigohar.